# Как получить данные из объекта подключенного по ссылке?

Tags: javascript

Подскажите пожалуйста как получить объект, его данные из функции подключенные по внешней ссылке. я имею ввиду есть файл, где выполняется одна часть по рандомному выводу данных. во втором файле мне нужно извлечь эти данные. в интернете не могу найти инфу. может кто подскажет где найти или как это называется - копирование, клонирование, инициализация?

```
[https://proweb.uz/javaScript/receipt.js][1]
```

это ссылка на файл к которому  мне нужно подключиться во втором файле.

https://proweb.uz/javaScript/receipt.js

Answer (score 0):

```js
console.log(receipt());
```

```html
<script src="https://proweb.uz/javaScript/receipt.js"></script>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25584830/how-to-load-external-js-script-from-url-in-node-js